# Ajax success function animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a request a quote form using Ajax and I finally have everything working the way I want it to (special thanks to a member here who helped me previously). There's only one aesthetic addition i'd like to make and i'm not sure how to go about doing it. I'd like the success message I have to use the slideInUp css animation when the Submit button is pressed, instead of it just appearing with no animation.

This is what I have so far..

```
$("#myform").submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
            var $this = $(this)
            var url = $this.attr('action') // get the action attribute of current form
            $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "submit.php",
                   data: $this.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
                   success: function(data)
                   {
                       $this.find('.fs-submit').css('background', '#1fae5b');
                       $this.find('.fs-submit').css('color', '#ffffff');
                       $this.find('.fs-submit').css('border', '#1fae5b');
                       $this.find('.fs-submit').prop('disabled', true);
                       $this.find('.fs-submit').val('Submitted').text('Submitted ✔');
                       $this.find('.success').css('display', 'inline');
                   }
                 });

        });
```

The HTML:

```
<button class="fs-submit" type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
<p class="success">Your request for a quote has been sent to us. We will get back to you shortly!</p>
```

And the CSS:

```
p.success{
     margin: 0 auto;
     display: none;
     color: #1fae5b;
     font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
     font-weight: 600;
     font-size: 14px;
}
```

Comment: Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/4jozsmvp/) ?

Comment: Yes, something similar to this. But is there any way to have it so that it uses the animate.css animation slideInUp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing in Google search results when searching for `css slideinup` is [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/anujashukla/pen/pgvapZ) with the necessary CSS:

```
.slideInUp {
  -webkit-animation-name: slideInUp;
  animation-name: slideInUp;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideInUp {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
    transform: translateY(100%);
    visibility: visible;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
@keyframes slideInUp {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
    transform: translateY(100%);
    visibility: visible;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

Using this CSS, rather than doing this:

```
$this.find('.success').css('display', 'inline');
```

do this

```
$this.find('.success').addClass('slideInUp');
```

Comment: Possibly because you have `display: none` on `.success` and the CSS changes the `visibility` style instead. Change your `.success` class to `visibility: hidden`